# FullCalendar - How to make it to only show a weekly calendar

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I'm working on a school project in which we are going to use a calendar with a weekly view on one site and a monthly view on another site, hopefully linked together in the end so the events stick to both calendars. But my main concern at the moment is how to make it show the current WEEK only, which should only show the days like in the monthly views without the time marks etc.

In short, I just want to reduce the calendar size to only show the current week, with the same design as the monthly view uses.
Hopefully someone can help me with this seemingly easy task.

Thanks in advance for ur help!

Comment: Which language/framework are you using?

Comment: For this application im using Javascript.

Answer (score 11):

Try this  http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/

```
$("#weekcalender").fullCalendar({
header: {
     left   : 'prev,next',
     center : 'title',
     right  : 'agendaDay',
    },
defaultView: 'basicWeek'
})
```

with the default view set as basicweek you can get rid of the Time display on the calendar